tiktok apii error 'unaudited_client_can_only_post_to_private_accounts'
I am trying to publish a video on tiktok by tiktok api but when I try I find this error
{
  error: {
    code: 'unaudited_client_can_only_post_to_private_accounts',
    message: 'Please review our integration guidelines at https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/content-sharing-guidelines/',
    log_id: '20241211044147B04842F6C17B7F4B4799'
  }
}


I am not understanding what is 'unaudited_client' and how can I fix this

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
